# Unable to Authenticate at Azure Portal

Tags: java, azure, adal

I have used https://github.com/satalyst/powerbi-rest-java to authenticate at azure portal to embed power bi reports in my application.

There is a class named Office365Authenticator which I used to authenticate using my credentials. I have provided

1. client id="3b54c59c-2602-4100-b4e5-xxxxxxxxxxxx"(which i presume is application id on azure portal)
2. tenant id="b3e3ea8a-1379-4a80-acdd-xxxxxxxxxxxx" (Directory Id)
3. username (azure portal login email)
4. password (azure portal login password)

   Office365Authenticator ads = new Office365Authenticator(CLIENT_ID, TENANT, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

But it throws an error

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90019: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials.\r\nTrace ID: 948699d9-0f5d-4dd8-af3d-xxxxxxxxxxxx\r\nCorrelation ID: 27a9bdc9-90c1-4b40-9fe8-xxxxxxxxxxxx\r\nTimestamp: 2019-03-07 14:27:04Z"}
```

I have search but have no exact clue why it is happening for my scenario when I have verified the tenant id is correct and the user is related with this tenant Id as can be seen in the attached image.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the ROPC(username and password), you should have the following parameters:

```
1. client_id: your application id in the azure portal
2. client_secret: you could create this key in the application
3. grant_type:password
4. username: the user account that you want in the azure portal
5. password: the password for your account
6. scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read email openid(here use the microsoft graph api as an example, and the related permissions: User.Read, email, openid)
```

For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request).

Comment: I was able to do it using simple REST API rather than using what JAVA API they have provided.